# exact speech word recognition

Tags: java, android

I used Android Speech-to-Text API (Recognizer Intent), for recognition of the word said by the user. But the problem is that it returns the accurate word after autocorrection. I want it returns the exact word (without correction) said by the user. Please suggest me any other android library for this feature or how can I got my feature inside the android inbuild speech to text API.
I also saw the google API for this but that is paid And that is also AI-based.

Comment: why don't you use android libraries for stt?

Comment: What is the problem with using AI technologies for this? Btw I think your question is too broad

Comment: No, I want the exact word said by the user, not with the correction. So that's why I don't want AI-based API. may you got my question, thanks.

Comment: I studied further about Speech-to-Text API (Recognizer Intent) of Android and got the intent returns an array of strings which match to out input. And the first one as the most accurate and rest is without corrected. and in the rest result, there may be a chance the exact word said by the user is present. but in this case also which on which basis I distinguish the exact word said by the user present in the rest of the list.  pardon me if there is a mistake in  English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want it to return the exact word (without correction) said by the user.

I think you misunderstand what speech recognition is capable of doing.

A speech recognizing system is only capable of recognizing an uttered word as being one of a number of possible words.  It doesn't ... and cannot ... tell you with 100% accuracy what the speaker actually said.

This applies to any speech recognition system, including a human listener.  (How many times have *you* had to ask someone to "Say that again please" ?)

The only way to determine with absolute certainly the exact words that were spoken is to ask the person who spoke them to type them in!  (And even then, they may not give you a 100% accurate answer, in some cases.)

In short, what you want is not possible.   Software cannot do it.  Humans cannot do it, even if they believe that they can<sup>1</sup>.  You need to adjust your expectations.

<sup>1 - The Two Ronnies - [Four Candles sketch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qu9MptWyCB8M)</sup>

---

Identifying / recommending better (more accurate) speech recognition software or services is off-topic.

Comment: ohh, ohk thanx Stephen